# How to connect to remote server from R studio

Tags: r

I need to connect to Unix server. I went through some sites and believe I may need to use 'ODBC', but not sure how.

Basically, I want some syntax which is equivalent of "RSUBMIT" in SAS. I want all the processing to be done in Remote Server as done by "RSUBMIT"  command in SAS. I don't want to download the dataset to my local pc.

Can you kindly help me if there is any way to achieve the same in R studio? 
I am running R studio -0.98.1102 and R -3.1.2.

There is a sas dataset on the server that I need access to.
In SAS I connect to server the following way-

```
        %let remhost=sasgrid.app.xxxx.com 7554; 
        signon remhost user=_prompt_ password=_prompt_;
```

I am trying to build a tree model on the dataset that is present on the server. The server does not have R or Rstudio.

Kindly let me know if you need any other information.

Regards,
Rajat

Comment: There aren't enough details in your question to answer (particularly regarding the server). However, you should try installing RStudio Server on the UNIX server, which would let you access RStudio on the server from a browser

Comment: I don't have authorization to install anything on the server. Is there anything that I can do at my end ?

Comment: This question doesn't have enough details about what is on the server, how it can be connected to, and what you are trying to run on it, to answer